# Is it possible to have per-app network/vpn/proxy settings

Tags: macos, applications, network, vpn, proxy

I have a few different applications on my Mac that ideally I would like to run with different network settings.

One app for work I need to run over my work VPN, but at the same time, I have another app I need to run over a proxy for testing. Currently, I can only work with one app at a time with the required network setup. Stop working with it, then setup my other network config.

Is there an app, or a way to specify via settings that an application should use a particular networking setup?

Answer (score 11):

There are two premium (paid) solutions that do this well.

- [MacProxy](http://www.tidalpool.ca/macproxy/index.html) ($30USD)
- [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/mac_download.htm) ($40USD)
- [TSocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net) is an open source solution, requires some command-line foo.