# Configure Skype proxy setting?

Tags: mac, network, proxy, skype

I would like to use Skype's proxy setting on Mac. However, when I click "Change",

[image]

it just takes me to **SystemPreferences -> Wifi -> Advanced -> Proxies**.

What am I supposed to do to set up a proxy for Skype? I wish to do this because others can resolve and attack me with booters very easily thanks to Skype.

**I would like a method that does not require an additional application. Please do not post links to apps which attempt to route the connections on a per-app basis. It should be possible to do this without one.**

Preferably, I would like a proxy "just for Skype". Not for the entire OS to use.

How can I configure a proxy to be used by just Skype?

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54557/is-it-possible-to-have-per-app-network-vpn-proxy-settings or http://superuser.com/questions/410142/how-to-route-traffic-through-a-specific-socks-proxy-on-a-per-app-basis

Comment: already saw that, those are all really ugly applications and i'd prefer to do this the hard way lol

Comment: Always helps if you mention what you already looked at. Saves a whole lot of wasted google time

Comment: Apologies :) i will edit the question

Comment: And as usual, the Windows version of Skype has all it needs to use a spécific proxy, but the mac version does not. Why did Microsoft **NOT** implement that "basic" functionality in the mac version?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Proxy in OS X of your choosing and let Skype use it.

Skype works with HTTPS and SOCKS types of Proxy.

Alternatively without setting up a Proxy and in order to protect your privacy in Skype you can simply use the Skype feature to Hide your IP.

Open Skype- Preferences - Advanced.

[image: Skype]

Comment: I would like a proxy "just for skype". Not for the entire OS to use. How can I configure the proxy to just be used by skype?

Comment: AFIK that can not be done, other than setting the whole system to that connection (proxy). As soon you set up a proxy you can tell Skype to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a proxy "just for Skype". The Skype developers have not programmed that option and therefore it does not exist.

Mac OS X and for example Windows only allow you to set a system-wide proxy.

Unless the developer of an application allows you to set an application-specific proxy, you cannot set a proxy without a third party application.